# App to copy text from youtube video and paste into a terminal

Tags: text-processing, youtube

On a linux machine, I watch many youtube videos associated with programming/coding.  I would like to try out the code that is being presented in the youtube video.  A useful app for me would be to be able to highlight the text on youtube video, copy the highlighted text (into clipboard or elsewhere), and then paste the text into a terminal to perform other operations.  Hopefully could avoid the pain and possible errors associated with retyping.  I am not talking about converting voice to text as has been asked before.

It might be possible to do a "selected region" screen capture of the text area and save to a graphics file in some format from which the text might be extracted.  I was hoping to see whether an app to do this directly and easily exists for linux.

Any ideas?    thanks,      tom kosvic

Answer (score 0):

*Posting this in case anyone finding the question in future has a different hardware requirement.*

macOS from Monterey & iOS/iPadOS from 15 can do this natively. For video you need to pause it first; it prefers to read from stills.

Image from [MacWorld - macOS Monterey: How to use Live Text and Visual Look Up](https://www.macworld.com/article/351669/macos-monterey-how-to-live-text-look-up-photos-quick-look-safari.html)
Hover your cursor over any text in an image, it will turn into a caret. Select by dragging, then as the cursor changes to a hand, drag to a text document or copy/paste like regular text.

[image]

Comment: That's what I would like to find for linux.     tom kosvic

Answer (score 0):

On Android or Windows, I either take a screenshot (or, if from a screen recording, a video capture image) and immediately "share" it with/to the Keeper App from Google Play Store before the toast message options fade away. Usually, I categorize/ label before saving, but not required.
Immediately after saving, press "view" so as Not to have to go back into keeper app from YT or gallery or whatever app you were sharing from.
Once image is added AND saved in the keeper app, additional options are available from the more button in the upper right (the vertical ellipsis).
If the more button is not visible, just tap the screen anywhere atop the image that you just saved to bring it into visibility.
Within the list of commands listed below "More button", select "Grab text from image" or capture text from image.
A toast message will pop up to confirm "text successfully copied / captured".
If you don't see toast message confirming success, repeat (press "more"...grab text from image").
Scroll down to the area just below the image (where the Title and Notes fields reside and you will see all of the text from the image available to copy and paste, usually without having to correct any characters.
I use it all the time to copy useful writing or text from portions of YouTube videos to make referential / study notes or to share text from an image that would be useful to a partner/teammate. Love it.

Answer (score 0):

There are some great FOSS tools, for many OS'. They are convenient to use, like the one for MacOs mentioned by @Tetsujin.
I am on `kubuntu` and like [`NormCap`](https://github.com/dynobo/normcap) (installed `AppImage (Binary)` for Linux).
You probably also would like [‘TextSnatcher’](https://github.com/RajSolai/TextSnatcher).